# A simple proof for the relationship between the eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix and its Cholesky decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, cholesky-decomposition

Can anyone present to me an *elegant elementary proof* of the relationship between the eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix and its Cholesky decomposition?

More formally, suppose $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n\times n$ positive definite matrix and let $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{R}^\top \mathbf{R}$ be its Cholesky decomposition. Establish the relationship between the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ and that of $\mathbf{R}$.

**EDIT (Additional remarks):** My question specifically wants to find, if possible, an equation or function, say $f$, that relates the eigenvalues, i.e., $f\left(\lambda_i(\mathbf{R})\right) = \lambda_i(\mathbf{A})$, with uniqueness up to order being considered if necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no such relation. If the spectrum of $A$ is a function of the spectrum of $R$, it would imply that
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ t&1}\pmatrix{1&t\\ 0&1}=\pmatrix{1&t\\ t&t^2+1}
$$
has a constant spectrum, but this is obviously not the case because our $A$ here has a non-constant trace.

In general, if $A=R^TR$ (regardless of whether this is a Cholesky decomposition or not) for a real square matrix $R$, the eigenvalues of $A$ are the squared *singular values* of $R$.

Comment: can you give a more detailed version of the proof or at least a reference text that explains your last line regarding the 'general' case?

Comment: @venrey Every textbook that covers singular value decomposition should have mentioned that the singular values of a (possibly non-square) matrix $M$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $M^\ast M$ (when $M$ is tall) or $MM^\ast$ (when $M$ is fat). I haven't any good reference at hand, but I think you may try *Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson, *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* by Gilbert Strang, another textbook of the same title by Peter Lax, or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition).

Answer (score 4):

For a positive definite matrix $A$, with $Q$ as eigenvector matrix and $\Lambda$ as eigenvalue matrix, we have

$$
A = Q \Lambda Q^T
$$

This can be rewritten as (since all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive) :

$$
A = (Q \sqrt{\Lambda}) (\sqrt{\Lambda} Q^T)
$$

So for $A = R^TR$, $R$ can be a matrix such that,

$$
R = \sqrt{\Lambda} Q^T
$$

Also we can multiply any orthogonal matrix $Q$ to this $R$ without changing the original $A = R^TR$ condition, because,

$$
A = (QR)^TQR = R^T(Q^TQ)R = R^TR
$$

So rewriting $R$ as $Q\sqrt{\Lambda} Q^T$, we see that eigenvalues of $R$ are square roots of eigenvalues of $A$

Comment: How can you be sure that the $\mathbf{R}$ is an upper (or lower) triangular as should be the case of Cholesky?

Comment: Ah yes you're right. You can only write $R$ as $\sqrt {D} L^T$. So I think we can only comment on the sign of eigenvalues of $R$ matching those of $A$ but not the values themselves.

Comment: Can you formalize your argument that, "the sign of eigenvalues of $\mathbf{R}$ matching those of $\mathbf{A}$ but not the values themselves"?

Comment: As the other answer states, there is no such relationship

Comment: If I understand this correctly, and to clarify the above, the singular values are the same, in general, as the eigenvalues only for positive definite symmetric matrices.  I think people confuse $L$ with $A$ with respect to this. However, since the $L$ in the Cholesky decomposition is not symmetric, even for a positive symmetric matrix $A$, the eigenvalues of the $L$ are *not* the square root of the eigenvalues of $A$. Instead, the singular values of $L$ are the square root of the eigenvalues of $A$. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Start with Cholesky form:
$$A = R^TR$$
let $R = DL$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix such that $D_{i, i} = R_{i, i}$, then $L_{i, i} = 1$ and $L$'s rows are $R$ divided by diagonals of $D$, which means $\text{det}(L) = 1$

Consider $A = (DL)^T(DL) = L^TD^2L$, then $\text{det}(A) = \text{det}(L)^2\text{det}(D)^2 = \lambda_1\lambda_2\cdots\lambda_n$.

Basically: $\prod_{i = 1}^n(D_{i, i})^2 = \prod_{i = 1}^n\lambda_i = \prod_{i = 1}^n(R_{i, i})^2$