# Eigenvalues when we have a root of a matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

**Question: Is it any easier to find eigenvalues of a matrix $M$, if we have it's root $S \cdot S^T = M$?**  (Please note that $S$ doesn't have to be triangular so this is not Cholesky).

If the answer is "no, in general", let' see if there is a solution in my particular case, when the matrix $M$ is composed from an already decomposed matrix:

Say that we have a symmetric matrix $K$ (covariance matrix). We have it's [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices):

$$K = Q \Lambda Q^T$$

where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues on the diagonal, $Q$ is orthogonal matrix ($Q^T = Q^{-1}$). Let's define root of matrix $K$:

$$R = Q {\sqrt \Lambda} Q^T$$

(Now $K = R \cdot R$, $R$ is symmetric as well).

**Now, the main question:** What can we say about the eigenvalues of $M = R \cdot 
(I - {1 \over n} J) \cdot R$?

($I$ is an identity matrix, $J$ is matrix of all 1's, $n$ is the number of rows and columns of these matrices.)
**Can the eigenvalues of $M$ be somehow easily computed from $\Lambda$ or $\sqrt{\Lambda}$, or do I have to do the costly eigenvalue decomposition again for $M$?**

PS: Not sure if this helps, but since $(I - {1 \over n} J)$ is idempotent,  $M = R \cdot (I - {1 \over n} J) (I - {1 \over n} J) \cdot R$, and so if we set $S = R \cdot (I - {1 \over n} J)$, then $M = S \cdot S^T$. (Please note that $S$ doesn't have to be triangular so this is not Cholesky).

Comment: [This post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/93119/34894) from MO and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2903455/81360) are relevant

Comment: [This paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S089547989324820X), with a [publicly available version here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.57.8041&rep=rep1&type=pdf), seems to take advantage of the Cholesky decomposition in some way

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you, but please note that the root $S$ is not necessarily a triangular matrix, so it's not exactly Cholesky.

Comment: Sure, but applying a $QR$ decomposition to $S^T$ gives you the Cholesky decomposition without too much more effort

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for your references. It's not clear to me how to put all them together to get the eigenvalues of $M$. Probably not so trivial. I'd be grateful for an answer if you know how to. Thanks.

Comment: not sure. Long story short, though, unless you're looking for numerical methods of approximating the eigenvalues, there isn't a way to make use of the Cholesky decomposition. Could you clarify what you mean by "the matrix $M$ is composed from an already decomposed matrix"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for the note about lack of analytical solutions and need for numerical ones! Yes, sure. I meant by it that $M$ is composed from parts of already decomposed matrix $K$:  $M = Q {\sqrt \Lambda} Q^T (I - {1 \over n} J) Q {\sqrt \Lambda} Q^T$

Comment: I see now that you explained that in your question, sorry about that. In any case, that gives me another idea

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is as follows: you have a matrix of the form
$$
M = Q {\sqrt \Lambda} Q^T \left(I - {1 \over n} J\right) Q {\sqrt \Lambda} Q^T \\
=Q {\sqrt \Lambda} Q^T (I) Q {\sqrt \Lambda} Q^T
- \frac 1n Q {\sqrt \Lambda} Q^T (J) Q {\sqrt \Lambda} Q^T\\
= Q \left[\Lambda 
- \frac 1n  [{\sqrt \Lambda} Q^Te][{\sqrt \Lambda} Q^Te]^T\right]Q^T,
$$
where $e$ denotes the vector of all $1$s.
In other words, you are looking for the eigenvalues of a rank-1 perturbation of a diagonal matrix.  From there, you have several methods at your disposal.  For instance, [the BNS formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Sorensen_formula) gives an expression for the eigenvectors of this matrix. The [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) gives you an expression for the characteristic polynomial, since
$$
\det((D + vv^T) + \lambda I) = \det((D + \lambda I) + vv^T) 
\\= (1 + v^T(D + \lambda I)^{-1}v)\det(D + \lambda I)
\\ = \det(D + \lambda I) + v^T\operatorname{adj}(D + \lambda I)v.
$$

Comment: Wow, thanks for this idea! Not sure I am able to follow on it yet :-) How did you come to the third part of the first equation, and what do you denote by $e$?

Comment: @Tomas Sorry for leaving that out! $e$ is the vector whose entries are all $1$. Noting that $J = ee^T$, I think you'll be able to see how to get from equation 3 to equation 2.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand the first equation.But I am completely lost in the second one ($det$).We want the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm) $p_M(z) = det(zI - M)$, right? But how is the equation related to this? What is $D$? Does $\lambda$ denote the same lambda from the decomposition of $K$, or is it the new lambda (eigenvalues of $M$)? What is $adj$? How can I use the determinant equation to find out the eigenvalues of $M$? Please be more specific and if possible make smaller, more trivial steps, my matrix algebra isn't on that level yet :-))

Comment: @Tomas I use a $\lambda$ instead of $z$. Here, $D = \Lambda$ and $v = \frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\Lambda}Q^Te$. "adj" denotes the classical adjoint.  This just gives us the characteristic polynomial, and we could find eigenvalues by finding its roots.

Comment: @Tomas Honestly if you want to get the most efficient possible method here, I recommend googling "eigenvalues of rank one update" and trying what comes up.