# Eigenvalues for structured matrix ($L^TL$ for constant lower triangular matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the $d \times d$ lower triangular matrix $L$ with entries $L_{ij} = 1$, $j \leq i$, and $L_{ij} = 0$ otherwise.

I am interested in computing the eigenvalues of $L^T D L$ with $D$ a diagonal matrix.

Is this easy to do in closed form? Even for the case $D = I$, I would be interested in help with this.

Also, do these type of matrices have a name? They seem to fall under the category of "arrow" structure.

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264969/proof-that-eigenvalues-are-the-diagonal-entries-of-the-upper-triangular-matrix-i

Comment: @RishiSonthalia The question you linked is about the eigenvalues of $L$. This question is about the eigenvalues of $L^TL$.

Comment: @Drew [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2903455/81360) and [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93119/interesting-relationships-between-cholesky-decomposition-and-diagonalization) might be relevant

Comment: @Drew If I remember correctly, the inverse of either $L^TL$ or $LL^T$ is tridiagonal and Toeplitz, which would lead to a nice closed form for the eigenvalues of $L^TL$.

Comment: This is pretty useful, thanks! I was aware that tridiagonal/Toeplitz had closed form eigenvalues. Is there a characterization of the inverse of such matrices?